# I'm using Laravel:Livewire star rating Components. I want to show total ratings in stars

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

The rating module is working well, number of ratings are also showing but I want to display total ratings in stars but I don't know how to write in blade view.

Livewire/ProductRating.php

```
public $rating;
    public $comment;
    public $currentId;
    public $product;
    public $hideForm;

    protected $rules = [
        'rating' => ['required', 'in:1,2,3,4,5'],
        'comment' => 'required',

    ];

    public function render()
    {
        $comments = Rating::where('product_id', $this->product->id)->where('status', 1)->with('user')->get();
        return view('livewire.product-ratings', compact('comments'));
    }

    public function mount()
    {
        if (auth()->user()) {
            $rating = Rating::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->where('product_id', $this->product->id)->first();
            if (!empty($rating)) {
                $this->rating  = $rating->rating;
                $this->comment = $rating->comment;
                $this->currentId = $rating->id;
            }
        }
        return view('livewire.product-ratings');
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate further on `I want to show total ratings in stars`, perhaps provide an example? Are you wanting to show the total number of ratings with an average, or maybe the total number of ratings by rating with their count?

Comment: I've already count total number of rating. I want to show these ratings in star. Like some people rate 4 some people rate 5. So I want to show all these ratings in stars.

Comment: May be that is called average

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like an [`average`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-avg) to me.

Comment: how can I do this in blade

Comment: You don't, you would use that in your `Livewire` `Component` and pass the result to your `Blade` view.

Comment: I need the code of all ratings sum and show it to all products pages. Can you give me the code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your `Rating` model has a property on it called `rating`, you could do the following to get the average rating for a product with the given `id`:

```
$average = Rating::where('product_id', $id)->avg('rating');
```